# Where to put things like dimensions in html/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am coming from an Android development background. In Android I would never say android:layout_margin=5dp, I would store 5dp in a dimens file and then refer to the dimension from there. Is there a similar best practice for html/css?

Comment: You should look into LESS or SASS.

Comment: HTML for mark up, CSS for styling.  As already mentioned, look into something like LESS/SASS/SCSS for building the CSS if you're used to setting things in one place and re-using them